# I am getting the error 'Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.'

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to implement firebase into my code, which is something I have don multiple times already before. But now, it is giving my an error I just do not understand.

I have kept in the google-services.json into the code and I have made all the necessary changes to both my app and project gradles. But when. i try to run the app, I keep getting this error

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

this is my project build gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The classpath is there, so I do not know what is wrong, help is required please